# installing mydns-ng on ubuntu 9.10 x64 gives error

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm trying to compile and install MyDns-ng but it gives strange error

```
    make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8'
avi@michael:/tmp/mydns-1.2.8$ make install
Making install in pkg
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/pkg'
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/pkg'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/pkg'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/pkg'
Making install in contrib
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/contrib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/contrib'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/contrib'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/contrib'
Making install in intl
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/intl'
if test "mydns" = "gettext" \
           && test '' = 'intl-compat.o'; then \
          /bin/sh `case "./mkinstalldirs" in /*) echo "./mkinstalldirs" ;; *) echo ".././mkinstalldirs" ;; esac` /usr/local/lib /usr/local/include; \
          /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libintl.h /usr/local/include/libintl.h; \
          /bin/sh ../libtool --mode=install \
            /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libintl.a /usr/local/lib/libintl.a; \
        else \
          : ; \
        fi
if test 'no' = yes; then \
          test yes != no || /bin/sh `case "./mkinstalldirs" in /*) echo "./mkinstalldirs" ;; *) echo ".././mkinstalldirs" ;; esac` /usr/local/lib; \
          temp=/usr/local/lib/t-charset.alias; \
          dest=/usr/local/lib/charset.alias; \
          if test -f /usr/local/lib/charset.alias; then \
            orig=/usr/local/lib/charset.alias; \
            sed -f ref-add.sed $orig > $temp; \
            /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 $temp $dest; \
            rm -f $temp; \
          else \
            if test yes = no; then \
              orig=charset.alias; \
              sed -f ref-add.sed $orig > $temp; \
              /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 $temp $dest; \
              rm -f $temp; \
            fi; \
          fi; \
          /bin/sh `case "./mkinstalldirs" in /*) echo "./mkinstalldirs" ;; *) echo ".././mkinstalldirs" ;; esac` /usr/local/share/locale; \
          test -f /usr/local/share/locale/locale.alias \
            && orig=/usr/local/share/locale/locale.alias \
            || orig=./locale.alias; \
          temp=/usr/local/share/locale/t-locale.alias; \
          dest=/usr/local/share/locale/locale.alias; \
          sed -f ref-add.sed $orig > $temp; \
          /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 $temp $dest; \
          rm -f $temp; \
        else \
          : ; \
        fi
if test "mydns" = "gettext"; then \
          /bin/sh `case "./mkinstalldirs" in /*) echo "./mkinstalldirs" ;; *) echo ".././mkinstalldirs" ;; esac` /usr/local/share/gettext/intl; \
          /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 VERSION /usr/local/share/gettext/intl/VERSION; \
          /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ChangeLog.inst /usr/local/share/gettext/intl/ChangeLog; \
          dists="COPYING.LIB-2.0 COPYING.LIB-2.1 Makefile.in config.charset locale.alias ref-add.sin ref-del.sin gmo.h gettextP.h hash-string.h plural-exp.h eval-plural.h os2compat.h libgnuintl.h loadinfo.h bindtextdom.c dcgettext.c dgettext.c gettext.c finddomain.c loadmsgcat.c localealias.c textdomain.c l10nflist.c explodename.c dcigettext.c dcngettext.c dngettext.c ngettext.c plural.y plural-exp.c localcharset.c localename.c osdep.c os2compat.c intl-compat.c"; \
          for file in $dists; do \
            /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./$file \
                            /usr/local/share/gettext/intl/$file; \
          done; \
          chmod a+x /usr/local/share/gettext/intl/config.charset; \
          dists="plural.c"; \
          for file in $dists; do \
            if test -f $file; then dir=.; else dir=.; fi; \
            /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 $dir/$file \
                            /usr/local/share/gettext/intl/$file; \
          done; \
          dists="xopen-msg.sed linux-msg.sed po2tbl.sed.in cat-compat.c COPYING.LIB-2 gettext.h libgettext.h plural-eval.c"; \
          for file in $dists; do \
            rm -f /usr/local/share/gettext/intl/$file; \
          done; \
        else \
          : ; \
        fi
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/intl'
Making install in po
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/po'
/bin/sh `case "./mkinstalldirs" in /*) echo "./mkinstalldirs" ;; *) echo ".././mkinstalldirs" ;; esac` /usr/local/share
mkdir -p -- /usr/local/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/share/locale': Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/mydns.mo': No such file or directory
installing es.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/mydns.mo
mkdir -p -- /usr/local/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/share/locale': Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/mydns.mo': No such file or directory
installing fr.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/mydns.mo
mkdir -p -- /usr/local/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/share/locale': Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/mydns.mo': No such file or directory
installing pt_BR.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/mydns.mo
if test "mydns" = "gettext"; then \
          /bin/sh `case "./mkinstalldirs" in /*) echo "./mkinstalldirs" ;; *) echo ".././mkinstalldirs" ;; esac` /usr/local/share/gettext/po; \
          for file in Makefile.in.in Makevars quot.sed boldquot.sed en@quot.header en@boldquot.header insert-header.sin Rules-quot  ; do \
            /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./$file \
                            /usr/local/share/gettext/po/$file; \
          done; \
        else \
          : ; \
        fi
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/po'
Making install in m4
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/m4'
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/m4'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/m4'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/m4'
Making install in doc
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/doc'
if ! test -f ../version.sed; then \
                cd .. && make sedfile; \
        fi
/bin/sh ../missing --run sed -f ../version.sed mydns.8.in | tr -s '\n' > mydns.8
/bin/sh ../missing --run sed -f ../version.sed mydnscheck.8.in | tr -s '\n' > mydnscheck.8
/bin/sh ../missing --run sed -f ../version.sed mydns.conf.5.in | tr -s '\n' > mydns.conf.5
/bin/sh ../missing --run sed -f ../version.sed mydns-conf.8.in | tr -s '\n' > mydns-conf.8
/bin/sh ../missing --run sed -f ../version.sed mydnsexport.8.in | tr -s '\n' > mydnsexport.8
/bin/sh ../missing --run sed -f ../version.sed mydnsimport.8.in | tr -s '\n' > mydnsimport.8
/bin/sh ../missing --run sed -f ../version.sed mydnsptrconvert.8.in | tr -s '\n' > mydnsptrconvert.8
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/share/info" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/info"
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/share/info': Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install-info-am] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/doc'
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/mydns-1.2.8/doc'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Anyone stumbled upon this? Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be root?

```
su
```

or

```
sudo bash
```

Comment: thanks ! none of the tutorials say u have to be root >_>

Comment: the key is this error (found toward the end of your logs): `/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/local/share/info': Permission denied` ... note the __"Permission denied"__ bit, that's your clue.

Comment: ohh , right! i didn't see that :(